# Setting user roles based on some kind of ownership in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, roles

In my Spring-based application, I currently have basic roles such as ADMIN, and USER.

Is it possible to define a user role such as PHOTO_UPLOADER, which inherits from USER, but also adds a check whether the user making the call is actually the owner of the photo?

I am tired of writing the same `if (currentUser.id == photo.uploader.id)` in my controller actions over and over again. It applies to other entities as well.

Answer (score 12):

You can handle it with ACLs like Tomasz Nurkiewicz suggested. But Spring Securitz ACLs are complex and poor documented. (The best resource I know for it is this Book: [Spring Security](http://www.springsecuritybook.com/) 3 - by the authors of Spring Security)

But If you really need only this simple `if (currentUser.id == photo.uploader.id)` test, then I would recommend an other technique.

It is possible to enhance the method security expressions you can use them in @PreAuthorize annotations. Like:

```
@PreAuthorize("isPhotoOwner(#photo)")
public void doSomething(final Photo photo) {
```

To implement such an expression `isPhotoOwner` the core is really simple:

```
public class ExtendedMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends MethodSecurityExpressionRoot {

    public ExtendedMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(final Authentication a) {
        super(a);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public boolean isPhotoOwner(final Photo photoObject) {
        if (photoObject == null) {
            return false;
        }

        Photo photo = (photo) photoObject;
        return photo.getCreator().getLogin().equals(authentication.getName());
    }
}
```

Unfortunaly there is some addtional work to to register the ExtendedMethodSecurityExpressionRoot. --- *I have no time at the moment, if you are willing to try this approach, then leave a commment, and I will descripe the rest*

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what types of data accessing technology you are using. i know you can write interceptor or event listener to do the security checking for hibernate. i think ibatis is also the same way. in my project, i wrote CRUD enable interface methods in the parent model/entity class, and doing security check in some events, such as before entity loading. spring security acl is a bit complex. implementing your security solution is more better.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome in the world of [ACLs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/domain-acls.html) - *access control list*. [This](http://grzegorzborkowski.blogspot.com/2008/10/spring-security-acl-very-basic-tutorial.html) tutorial is rather old but pretty comprehensive.

Comment: Well, it was old in 2012 so now in 2017 I guess it's "super old". Is there anything new to ACLs in Spring? It's still hard to get started with that - or is there already an alternative?