# Spring Data REST - How to handle object ownership

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-rest

How do I handle ownership in a REST interface in a Spring Data REST application?

Using the typical Manager manages Employee(s) scenario where I have a business rule that a Manager can only view an Employee's information if the Employee is managed by the Manager accessing the data:

```
Manager | Employee
--------+---------
1       | A
1       | B
2       | C
```

The `GET /employees/C` request should return the Employee record when accessed by Manager 2, but should return a `400 Bad Request` (or something similar) for Manager 1. How do I accomplish this using Spring Data REST/Spring Security?

Comment: What is your return type for the web service? Is it a List of employee objects or just an employee?

Comment: It would be the `findById` method I believe, so just a single `Employee`.

Comment: aah, I misread your question.. Yes it is possible in Spring Security, via ACL -  Access Control Lists.

Comment: Any links to good resources for ACL would be appreciated

Comment: Yes, I am searching a useful one which you can follow. Have you worked on Spring Security? ACLs are a bit hard to grasp IMHO.

Comment: I haven't really used Spring Security much. I really like the simplicity and the standards-compliant nature of Spring Data REST for my RESTful web services, but adding ANY business logic seems to be a huge pain. I'm not sure what route I'll go, but your answer is exactly what I was looking for so I'll mark it correct. Thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, this is possible via Spring Security ACL. A sample project from github is [here](https://github.com/charybr/spring-data-rest-acl)

You could also achieve this in a different way, as per this post - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495746/setting-user-roles-based-on-some-kind-of-ownership-in-spring-security)

Having said this, it is complicated. Spring Security and ACL are not that well documented. If you need more links to this answer, do let me know.