# What would a conditional privilege implementation look like using Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, permissions

What I mean by 'conditional' privileges is, for example: Say we have Event e. The user who CREATED Event e should be able to delete Event e and invite additional users to Event e, but only that user.

From tutorials I've seen, permissions and roles seem static, for example:
Doctor has a role doctor, with permissions x, y and z, but that is it...pretty static.

Is there a simple way to conditionally manage permissions with Spring Security?

Or would this be something better suited for the front-end? For example, the view would show a 'delete event' button only if the resource data for that particular Event confirms that the Event creator's ID is in fact the same ID stored in session memory/keychain/whatever for the currently logged in user, type of thing.

Thanks

Comment: Something like `@PreAuthorize(#event.owner == principal.username)` on the method that is doing the delete. Or by using the ACL features of Spring Security.

Comment: Oh cool, is there a reason the hashtag is there before event? Or where did you get that information so I can read about it. Thanks!

Comment: While the accepted answer hints at an ACL based approach this is complex to implement. You can achieve the same more easily using dynamic expressions on endpoints (web security expressions) or by applying method level security. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html

Comment: @TylerDurden how to write expressions is explained in the reference guide in some detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

> Or would this be something better suited for the front-end?
>   ...show a 'delete event' button only if...

NO. Not as a reliable line of defence, no.

Well that probably depends on a tech stack, architecture etc, but as a rule of thumb, you shouldn't do it. I didn't write servlets/jsp, but I used spring security in a rich client (swing) application and even though we had all the control (I mean, we could *guarantee* that user cannot access some function no other way than clicking a button), we secured our *models*, not the gui.

You shouldn't be able to call `Entity#delete` no matter how you call it - via button click event or calling it directly in a test. In case of web application, imagine you don't display a button, but an attacker knows that button leads to `example.com/entity?action=delete` URL or something like that, he could access it directly even if you don't render the button.

With regard to the main question, spring security, roughly speaking, has two parts: RBAC and ACL. What you need seems to be the ACL part. Read some howtos and articles about [domain security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html), it's a pretty complex stuff, but it can be suited for your needs for sure (with some effort, of course). What you described in a first paragraph may be achieved easily because every object has it's owner and it can be exploited.

Also, [here's a good advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9496109/6948900).

Edit: just to clear things up for future visitors. Point was: there should be some logic on the front-end, but it **must not be the only security logic**. Of course there's no need to clutter UI with buttons leading to functions you can't access.

Comment: Right, it is not necessary you are correct, but for instance if you have a Tweet on Twitter, and you are viewing it, the view must have some logic to display a button or whatever UI they use in order to delete the Tweet. This UI will only display if you are the author of the Tweet, and if not, it won't be visible.